# How can I quickly fix EBCDIC control characters in large files using Perl?

Tags: windows, regex, perl, performance

My apologies if this comes across as a newbie question. I'm not a Perl developer, but am trying to use it within an automation process, and I've hit a snag.

The following command runs quickly (a few seconds) on my Linux system (Ubuntu 9.10 x64, Perl 5.10), but is extremely slow on a Windows system (Windows 2003 x86, Strawberry Perl 5.12.1.0).

```
perl -pe 's/\x00\x42\x00\x11/\x00\x42\x00\xf0/sgx' inputfile > outputfile
```

The pattern to find/replace hex characters is intended to fix EBCDIC carriage control characters in a file that is between 500MB to 2GB in size. I'm not sure if this is even the most efficient way to do this, but it would seem to do the trick... if only it would run quickly on the Windows system it needs to run on.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is your Windows shell? I wouldn't think that single quotes work as an argument delimiter in the standard CMD shell.

Comment: Just the standard CMD shell.  I haven't had issues with single quotes in the past, but I haven't tried it with Perl before either.  I'm running with double-quotes now, and it's showing the same behavior.

Comment: So the command line you posted works on Windows, but it just works slowly?

Comment: The command does not "work" on Windows. Add `-w` to the command line: **Useless use of a constant in void context at -e line 1.**

Comment: Just a nit: the /s and /x flags don't do anything there.

Comment: @bitbucket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148388/perl-best-practices-what-shouldnt-i-use/148563#148563

Comment: @rickyboone: If you are going to multi-post, at least mention that you did so. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=862679

Answer (score 3):

Note that there is a distinction between text and binary files on Windows. Text files are subject to automatic EOL conversion which I assume might add to the run time as well as potentially messing up your binary substitution (presumably not the case here).

Also, there is no point using the `/sx` with this substitution.

I think the heart of the matter boils down to this: With the `-p` switch, you are supposed to be processing the input line-by-line. Where is the first EOL (as understood by `perl`) in the file? Are you trying to read a huge string into memory, do the `s///` on it and write out?

How about using the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
$/ = "\x00\x42\x00\x11";
$\ = "\x00\x42\x00\xf0";

while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    print;
}
```

Also, you absolutely need to use double-quotes on Windows. Compare and contrast:

```
C:\Temp> perl -pe 's/perl/merl/' t.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
...
```

```
C:\Temp> perl -pe "s/perl/merl/" t.pl
#!/usr/bin/merl
...
```

Comment: My intent is for perl to treat the input and output as binary, with no EOL conversion.

Comment: (sorry, forgot "enter" in these comments immediately sent them...)  The script I ran above (perl test.pl < input > output) seemed to add an extra \x42\x00\xf0 at the end of the file, though it was much faster and got everything else within the file correct.  Am I right to assume that's due to something Windows is doing due to EOL conversion?  Should I not use STDIN and STDOUT and call specific input/output files in a binary mode?